# MYSQL: Getting salary summation for different types of employees

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the salary information for different employee types in a hospital.  When I do a sum on the salary it works by giving me the total salary for that department.  However, when I try to break it down by employee type, I get NULL as a result.  How can I get just the salary of the specific type of employee within a department?  It seems the following code I'm using is incorrect:

SUM(CASE WHEN doctor.doctorID THEN employee.salary ELSE NULL END) AS doctor_pay,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.departmentID,
    COUNT(o.doctorID) AS number_of_doctors,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.doctorID THEN e.salary ELSE NULL END) AS doctor_pay,
    COUNT(r.residentID) AS number_of_residents,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.residentID THEN e.salary ELSE NULL END) AS resident_pay,
    COUNT(n.nurseID) AS number_of_nurses,
    SUM(CASE WHEN n.nurseID THEN e.salary ELSE NULL END) AS nurse_pay,
    COUNT(x.patientID) AS patient_count,
    SUM(e.salary) AS total_cost
FROM department d
    INNER JOIN person p ON d.departmentID = p.departmentID
    LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID = p.personID
    LEFT JOIN doctor o ON o.employeeID = p.personID
    LEFT JOIN resident r ON r.employeeID = p.personID
    LEFT JOIN nurse n ON n.employeeID = p.personID
    LEFT JOIN patient x ON x.patientID = p.personID
GROUP BY d.departmentID
```

Comment: I have also tried the following:

CASE WHEN doctor.employeeID = employee.employeeID THEN SUM(employee.salary) ELSE NULL END AS total_doctor_pay

But am getting the same full total for all employee types.

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone wondering:

SUM(CASE WHEN doctor.employeeID = employee.employeeID THEN employee.salary ELSE NULL END) AS total_doctor_pay

Looks like I didn't use a conditional operator after WHEN.